# Xcode: Why is my timer counting 2 seconds on every tick?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nstimer, countdown

Hi I have a timer that should count from 12:00 minutes to 0:00 in an iphone app!
But when it starts it counts like this;
11:58
11:56
11:54
11:52

it is counting 2 seconds on every tick.

this is the code in the start button code:

```
tid.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%.2d",minuter,sekunder];
timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(tidklick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This is the method tidklick:

```
-(void) tidklick
{

tiden -= 1;
sekunder = tiden % 60;
minuter= (tiden - sekunder) / 60;
tid.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%.2d",minuter,sekunder];

}
```

This is the code in the beginning..

```
 int tiden=720;
 int sekunder;
 int minuter;
```

This appears in the NSLog that I put in the method...

```
2012-04-26 06:41:38.562 Matte [288:f803] tiden: 719
sekunder: 59
 2012-04-26 06:41:38.607 Matte [288:f803] tiden: 718
 sekunder: 58
 2012-04-26 06:41:39.562 Matte[288:f803] tiden: 717
 sekunder: 57
 2012-04-26 06:41:39.607 Matte[288:f803] tiden: 716
  sekunder: 56
 2012-04-26 06:41:40.562 Matte [288:f803] tiden: 715
 sekunder: 55
 2012-04-26 06:41:40.607 Matte [288:f803] tiden: 714
 sekunder: 54
```

I have tried to make a new timer with a new name and new method, but it still counts 2.. Can it have something to do with the fact that I have alot of buttons and stuff on the screen? Some memory error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode is adding 2 instead of 1 all the time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320817/xcode-is-adding-2-instead-of-1-all-the-time)

Comment: Where did you put the timer method? It's probably in the wrong place.

Answer (score 5):

Your logic looks fine. Are you sure you’re not creating the timer twice?

Comment: Yes, I have :O I can't find another timer anyway :S

Comment: omg, this is driving me crazy :O I don't know, but can it have something to do with the fact that I have a lot of buttons and labels on that screen? :S

Answer (score 2):

you code don't have problem, try logging first

then you will know if it count every 2 sec or it refresh UI at every 2 sec

```
-(void) tidklick
{

tiden -= 1;
sekunder = tiden % 60;
// add log here
NSLog(@"tiden: %d\n sekunder: %d",tiden,sekunder);

minuter= (tiden - sekunder) / 60;
tid.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%.2d",minuter,sekunder];

}
```

And you can try to run the timer in background thread

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(schedule) withObject:nil];

- (void) schedule {
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                              target:self
                                    selector:@selector(run:)
                                    userInfo:nil
                                     repeats:YES]
     retain];

[runLoop run];
[pool release];
}


-(void) run:(id) sender{

// you should handle the thread-safe 
tiden -= 1;
sekunder = tiden % 60;
// add log here
NSLog(@"tiden: %d\n sekunder: %d",tiden,sekunder);
minuter= (tiden - sekunder) / 60;
NSString *test =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%.2d",minuter,sekunder];

[label performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:test waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Comment: I dont get anything in the log? :O

Comment: I noticed that when I hit the button that invalidates the timer, the timer counts as normal... and if I hit menu--> start again, it counts 3 seconds per tick... and then if it invalidates, the timer counts 2 secoonds per tick again.. start again= counts 4 times per tick, invalidates= counts 3 seconds per tick... and so on...

It seems like it is a hidden timer that starts, and does not invalidate when the other does that...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes running from xcode can make things really slow. As previously stated the logic looks fine. You could try running it on the phone, but not from xcode. This might work with the simulator as well. Not sure about that though.

Comment: I have to pay 99 dollars to be able to run it on my phone right?

Comment: @user1344659 Short answer yes, long answer no. Assuming you have a "normal" configuration then you have to pay for the program, however there are some work-arounds for jailbroken devices.

Comment: Ok, it is not jailbroken tho! I've tried in so many ways, it is still counting 2 seconds eack time :S