# Xcode is adding 2 instead of 1 all the time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, timer, addition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode: Why is my timer count 2 seconds on every tick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318761/xcode-why-is-my-timer-count-2-seconds-on-every-tick)

In my app I have a timer that should go from 12:00 to 0:00, but it counts 2 seconds on every tick like this:

```
11.58
11.56
11.54
11.52 and so on..
```

this is the code in the start button code:

```
tid.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%.2d",minuter,sekunder];
timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                target:self
                selector:@selector(tidklick)
                userInfo:nil
                repeats:YES];
```

This is the method tidklick:

```
-(void) tidklick
{
    tiden -= 1;
    sekunder = tiden % 60;
    minuter= (tiden - sekunder) / 60;
    tid.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%.2d",minuter,sekunder];
}
```

This is the code in the beginning..

```
int tiden=720;
int sekunder;
int minuter;
```

and also when I hit a certain button, this should happen: `i++;`

but it seems like `i` gets added by `2` every time I hit the button....

What is wrong? :S Seems like something with Xcode and not my code?

EDIT: Now I noticed that when I hit the button that should stop the timer in the end(timer invalidate), it counts as normal... It counts one second at a time that is!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is soo long, so it you wont be able to check the hole thing anyway :P but I can add the timer part..

Comment: @user1344659 You asked the same question 2 hours ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318761/xcode-why-is-my-timer-count-2-seconds-on-every-tick

Comment: yes, I know.. But now I saw that something happened to i aswell... that 1 is converted to 2 somehow... :S

Comment: @user1344659 Perhaps you should have updated your original question then!

Comment: Not an Xcode question. Retagged.

Comment: how is it not an xcode question? :O

Comment: @user1344659 -- Xcode is the IDE.  Your question is for the language/environment you're using -- Objective-C and iOS.

Comment: Stick an NSLog in `tidklick` and see how often the routine is called.

Comment: Yeah but I think there is something wrong with xcode because it adds 2 instead of 1 all the time.. It worked with the button before.. and I'm pretty sure that I wrote the correct code!

Comment: I think it is fairly safe to assume that you haven't found a bug in Xcode (or Objective C), the bug will be in your code.

Comment: NSLog(@"Some string with some object: %@", someObject);  Or simply use a breakpoint.

Comment: You're likely creating the timer twice.  Recheck your code, and see if you are scheduling `timer` more than once.

Comment: You might try what I just tried:  copy the code you posted into an empty project.  Runs fine.  Start another timer right after the first: counts by two as @AMayes predicted.  Who's calling it twice?  Put breakpoint on scheduleTimer and look at the stack.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of the question, when you hit your button: Have you made sure that your selector for the button isn't being called twice -- for instance when the button is pressed down and then again when it is lifted up.

Comment: Yes I'm absolutely sure!

Answer (score 0):

When you say you 'hit the button', what is your button hitting code? There are several events that take place on a button "hit" (most notably button down and up events) which if you are not handling properly could increment `i` multiple times in a single 'hit'.

This could also be the reason the timer is doing down by two instead of one -- when you 'hit' the start button you are launching two timers instead of one, causing one second *per timer* to be decremented per second.

Answer (score 0):

For better time counting try to use NSDate methods:
[NSDate date] for start value and [NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime] to get time shift from the start.

Timer firing interval is *approximately* equals to 1 second.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think that will change so it only counts one time per tick right?